# How to extract all the text from a file using python

Tags: python, extract

**I have a string like** :- 'hi125get9itwhat8989'

**How could I extract only the that is** 'higetitwhat'

**In Python**

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isalpha.asp

Make a for loop for instance `for x in word` and than check every x if its a letter using `x.isAlpha()` and you can just add it to a new string

```
res = ""
for x in word:
    if x.isalpha():
        res += ch
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using **.isdigit()**

```
text = "hi125get9itwhat8989"
chars = [i for i in text if not i.isdigit()]
clean_text = ''.join(chars)
```